# LinkAssemblies task failed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata      
item 'System.Void Android.Widget.TextView::SetTextAppearance(System.Int32)' (defined in 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Android.Widget.TextView::SetTextAppearance(System.Int32)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    FeedReader.Droid
```

I am trying to build My Xamarin.Adroid project for release. But i keep getting this error. General consensus on the web is that that my Targeting framework and minimum SDK versions have to be so and so, but I have tried them all to no avail.

[image]

Both those SDK's are installed on my machine, I also have the latest preview of Xamarin forms added.

[image]

Nothing I am trying seems to work. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22358/building-release-version-for-android-failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the method `Android.Widget.TextView::SetTextAppearance(System.Int32)` first appeared in API23: M. You'll need to change your compile and/or target versions to point to M.

Answer (score 0):

After updated xamarin version i start getting thi error. Clean project first then build it again. fixed for me. Rebuild not working.