# Error while building apk from Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created Xamarin.Forms Project. UWP project is working fine and able to generate the bundle . 
Issue is coming when I am trying to Deploy/ Run android project. I want my app compatible from Android Version 4.0 (API Level 14) but getting below error. When I set the API level to 23 then able to deploy the/Run project. It is even not working when I am setting to android version 5 or 5.1. What changes should I made in my PCL or Droid project so that it runs for all API level from 14 to 23. I have installed SDK for all level of the API through SDK Manager.

> error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException:
>   error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Void
>   Android.Widget.TextView::SetTextAppearance(System.Int32)' (defined in
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null') from 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be
>   resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve
>   System.Void Android.Widget.TextView::SetTextAppearance(System.Int32)
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody
>   body) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process() 1>C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext
>   context) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions
>   options, LinkContext& context) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 1>C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception
>   innerException, String message, Object[] args) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1571,5):
>   error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LinkAssemblies task failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443842/linkassemblies-task-failed)

Comment: Also closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424308/the-linkassemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly

Comment: I did lot of research and found some reasons which may lead to this error . See http://www.dkumar.co.in/2016/12/the-linkassemblies-task-failed_8.html